# Tag badges not shown in Android app's Achievements

Tags: bug, android-app, tag-badges, achievements-dialog

A couple of hours ago, I earn a gold tag badge for [java](/questions/tagged/java) on Stack Overflow. It's [perfectly visible on my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/44/java?userid=2422776) and on the topbar achievement list when accessed via the browser. On the Android app, it's shown on my profile page, but not displayed in today's achievement list.

I received the Civic Duty badge on Meta Super User, and it **did** appear in the achievement list in the app. Perhaps this behavior (bug?) is restricted to tag badges?

I'm using version 1.0.51 of the app on a Nexus 4.

Comment: Normal badges do appear on Achievement list, so I retagged it as a bug of [tag:tag-badges] (I couldn't test it since it's a long way to get another tag badge)